# Can't load package : The semaphore timeout has expired

Tags: delphi

I'm using Delphi 11. Starting today, i'm receiving this error everytime i open or save a project. Never saw this before. Any hints ?

[image]

Comment: On that diaog press `Ctrl+C`, then paste the text into your question instead of posting screenshots. No need to re-type it - that's prone to mistype or forget words (like "period"). Hint: works for all other dialogs, too.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Actually after posting this question, i tried to restart Windows and the problem is gone. Don't know exactly why / what happened, but it's fixed now.

Comment: "_Restart Windows_" is no helpful answer to anyone. On top it doesn't explain anything on how to prevent a problem.

Comment: @AmigoJack For it was helpful, as it fixed the issue